# How to keep track of a variable in pyspark so i can increment it by a column value and save it to another column?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

**`I made another question with more specific details and better explanation, so i've got some answers that solved it, link for the question`**: [PySpark - Cumulative sum with limits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72980095/pyspark-cumulative-sum-with-limits)

I have a dataframe with a column containing 1, 0 or -1 and my objective is to create another column in my dataframe that have an value in range (1 to 5) starting from 3 and it will increment or decrement based on the column containing the 1, 0 or -1.

```
+---+-----+
|var|expec|
+---+-----+
|  1|  4  |
|  1|  5  |
|  0|  5  |
| -1|  4  |
|  1|  5  |
|  1|  5  |
| -1|  4  |
+---+-----+
```

I tried window function to sum but the lag function don't seem to support dynamic values, the issue here is that I have to know the value of the previous element.

I tried using reduce to create a new dataframe with the value but I just don't get how to cumulate the rows to return in de reduce function, code bellow:

```
def calc_rec(acm, row):
    acm_ = []
    if (type(acm) == type([])):
        cur = acm[1][-1]
        res = acm[0]
        rows_ = acm[1]
    elif (acm == 3):
        res = acm
        cur = row
        rows_ = []
        rows_.append(Row(resc=acm,valor=row.valor))
    x = res + cur.valor
    if x > 5:
        x = 5
    elif x <= 0:
        x = 1
    rows_.append(Row(resc=x, valor=cur.valor))
    acm_ = [x, rows_]
    return acm_
```

Comment: How do you order the rows?

Comment: I order it by user_id and date

Answer (score 1):

I added an id for ordering rows:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
df = (
    df
    .withColumn('id', f.monotonically_increasing_id())
    .withColumn('expec', 3 + f.sum(f.col('var')).over(Window.partitionBy().orderBy(f.col('id'))))
    .drop('id')
)
```

Comment: I'm not sure that using `monotonically_increasing_id` will always preserve the order. Data may be split between hundreds/ thousands of nodes. How does the driver know which executor goes before which? So, if there's no order from the beginning, it seems `monotonically_increasing_id` cannot magically create one.

Comment: I asked if there’s a column to order the dataframe by, but got no response. Now they can replace the id column in my response with any column that can be used to order the dataframe.

Comment: True, if OP replaces this column with his ordering column, then this solution should work.

Comment: Yeah, like ZygD sayed when i used window to sum the value did'nt seen to increase properly because i need to keep track of the previews value of expec to increase or decrease it based on it, the 3 will be used just in the start of it, then the next base will be the first iteration.