# PySpark: How to create a column based on the previous value from the same column?

Tags: pyspark

Dear PySpark community:

I would like to calculate the *estimate_day_to_sustain* before supply. The original code is written in SAS using 'retain' statement, however, I cannot find a way to solve it in PySpark. Please help, thanks!

input data:

[image]

output data:

[image]

Algorithm:

1. On day 1: **current** estimate_day_to_sustain=**current** day
2. On other days:

   1> if **previous** estimate_day_to_sustain + **previous** supply <= **current** day;
   then **current** estimate_day_to_sustain = **current** day

   2> else **current** estimate_day_to_sustain= **previous** estimate_day_to_sustain + **previous** supply

Explanation of the algorithm:

1. on day 1: the estimate_day_to_sustain is 1; by the end of the day, 3 days of supply arrive
2. on day 3, we have 1+3=4 days of supply (from previous row), and it's day 3, so the estimate_day_to_sustain is 4;by the end of the day, 1 days of supply arrive
3. on day 9, we have 4+1=5 days of supply (from previous row), but it's already day 9, so the estimate_day_to_sustain is 9(**this is the tricky part**);by the end of the day, 5 days of supply arrive
4. on day 10, we have 9+5=14 days of supply (from previous row), and it's day 10, so the estimate_day_to_sustain is 14;by the end of the day, 9 days of supply arrive
5. on day 11, we have 14+9=23 days of supply (from previous row), and it's day 11, so the estimate_day_to_sustain is 23;by the end of the day,1 days of supply arrive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ways to do it -

- using arrays, [`aggregate()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.aggregate.html) and lambda function, *inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72982660/8279585)* (SPARK 3.1+)
- using rdd, [`flatMapValues()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.RDD.flatMapValues.html) and python function

using your input data

```
data_sdf.show()

# +---+------+
# |day|supply|
# +---+------+
# |  1|     3|
# |  3|     1|
# |  9|     5|
# | 10|     9|
# | 11|     1|
# +---+------+
```

Spark does not retain a sort order like SAS data steps do. So, we will have to sort the array or list wherever required.

---

### Using arrays, [`aggregate()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.aggregate.html) and lambda function

*SPARK 3.1+*

create day-supply structs and collect it to create an array of the said structs. The [`array_sort()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.array_sort.html) is used to order the array of structs by the day field (first element within struct). The `aggregate()` takes in an initial value and applies a function to each element of the provided array. So, the initial value is the array's first struct, and the lambda function is applied to each of the remaining structs. The [`array_union()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.array_union.html) is used to append the newly created array, after applying the lambda function, to the initial value recursively. Finally, the `inline()` function is used to create separate columns from the newly created array of structs. Detailed explanation on its workings can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72982660/8279585).

```
data2_sdf = data_sdf. \
    withColumn('day_supply_struct', func.struct(func.col('day'), func.col('supply'))). \
    groupBy(func.lit(1).alias('group_field')). \
    agg(func.array_sort(func.collect_list('day_supply_struct')).alias('ds_struct_arr'))

# +-----------+------------------------------------------+
# |group_field|ds_struct_arr                             |
# +-----------+------------------------------------------+
# |1          |[{1, 3}, {3, 1}, {9, 5}, {10, 9}, {11, 1}]|
# +-----------+------------------------------------------+

# create new field within the struct
data3_sdf = data2_sdf. \
    withColumn('arr_struct_w_est_days', 
               func.aggregate(func.slice(func.col('ds_struct_arr'), 2, data_sdf.count()), 
                              func.array(func.col('ds_struct_arr')[0].withField('estimate_days', func.col('ds_struct_arr')[0]['day'])), 
                              lambda x, y: func.array_union(x, 
                                                            func.array(y.withField('estimate_days', 
                                                                                   func.when(func.element_at(x, -1)['estimate_days'] + func.element_at(x, -1)['supply'] <= y['day'], y['day']).
                                                                                   otherwise(func.element_at(x, -1)['estimate_days'] + func.element_at(x, -1)['supply'])
                                                                                   )
                                                                       )
                                                            )
                              )
    )

# +-----------+------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
# |group_field|ds_struct_arr                             |arr_struct_w_est_days                                      |
# +-----------+------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
# |1          |[{1, 3}, {3, 1}, {9, 5}, {10, 9}, {11, 1}]|[{1, 3, 1}, {3, 1, 4}, {9, 5, 9}, {10, 9, 14}, {11, 1, 23}]|
# +-----------+------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+

# create columns using the struct fields
data3_sdf. \
    selectExpr('inline(arr_struct_w_est_days)'). \
    show()

# +---+------+-------------+
# |day|supply|estimate_days|
# +---+------+-------------+
# |  1|     3|            1|
# |  3|     1|            4|
# |  9|     5|            9|
# | 10|     9|           14|
# | 11|     1|           23|
# +---+------+-------------+
```

---

### using rdd, [`flatMapValues()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.RDD.flatMapValues.html) and python function

create a python function to calculate estimate days while keeping track of the previous calculated values. It takes in a group of row-lists (`groupBy()` is used to identify the grouping) and creates a list of rows-lists.

```
# best to ship this function to all executors in case of huge datasets
def estimateDaysCalc(groupedRows):

    res = []
    frstRec = True

    for row in groupedRows:
        if frstRec:
            frstRec = False
            # the first day will have a static value
            estimate_days = row.day
        else:
            if prev_est_day + prev_supply <= row.day:
                estimate_days = row.day
            else:
                estimate_days = prev_est_day + prev_supply
        
        # keep track of the current calcs for next row calcs
        prev_est_day = estimate_days
        prev_supply = row.supply
        prev_day = row.day

        res.append([item for item in row] + [estimate_days])

    return res
```

run the function on the RDD using `flatMapValues()` and extract the values. A sort on the `day` field is required, and a `sorted()` is used to sort the group of row-lists by the field (`ok.day`).

```
data_vals = data_sdf.rdd. \
    groupBy(lambda gk: 1). \
    flatMapValues(lambda r: estimateDaysCalc(sorted(r, key=lambda ok:ok.day))). \
    values()
```

create schema for the new values

```
data_schema = data_sdf. \
    withColumn('dropme', func.lit(None).cast('int')). \
    drop('dropme'). \
    schema. \
    add('estimate_days', 'integer')
```

create dataframe using the newly created values and schema

```
new_data_sdf = spark.createDataFrame(data_vals, data_schema)

new_data_sdf.show()

# +---+------+-------------+
# |day|supply|estimate_days|
# +---+------+-------------+
# |  1|     3|            1|
# |  3|     1|            4|
# |  9|     5|            9|
# | 10|     9|           14|
# | 11|     1|           23|
# +---+------+-------------+
```

Comment: Hi Samkart: Thank you so much for the answer! I tried your first approach, however, at "# create new field within the struct" "func.aggregate" , it produced error : "Module pyspark.sql.functions does not contain an attribute aggregate. Please review your code.". Then I replaced with "data2_sdf.agg", still error: "There is an incorrect call to a Column object in your code. Please review your code." Can you check this for me? Thanks! My Pyspark version is 3.0.2

Comment: @Bobby as mentioned in the answer, that approach is only available starting spark 3.1