# Dynamically update a Spark dataframe column when used with lag and window functions

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, dynamic, window-functions, lag

I would like to generate the below dataframe

[image]

Here, I am calculating the "adstock" based on the column "col_lag" and an engagement factor 0.9 as below:

```py
# window
windowSpec  = Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy("dt")

# create the column if it does not exist
if ('adstock' not in df.columns):
    df = df.withColumn("adstock",lit(0))

df = df.withColumn("adstock", (col('col_lag') + (lit(0.9)*(lag("adstock", 1).over(windowSpec)))))
```

When I run the above, somehow the code does not generate values after two or three rows and gives something like below:

[image]

I have around 125000 Ids and weekly data from 2020-01-24 to current week. I tried various methods like `rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, 1)` or creation of another column etc., but have not been successful.

I would appreciate any suggestions in this regard.

Comment: When calculating the values for `adstock` you cannot use "earlier" values from the same column as input for the calculation. Spark will try to run the calculations in parallel and might see a row where the `adstock` value has not yet been updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spark does not do calculations going from row to row, so it cannot access the result of previous row of the current calculation. To go around this, you may move all the values for the same id to one row and build a calculation logic from there. Higher-order function `aggregate` allows to do kind-of loops with the ability to access the previous value.

Input:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(1, '2020-10-07', 1),
     (1, '2020-10-14', 2),
     (1, '2020-10-21', 4),
     (1, '2020-10-28', 0),
     (2, '2021-09-08', 1),
     (2, '2021-09-15', 2),
     (2, '2021-09-22', 0),
     (2, '2021-09-29', 0)],
    ['id', 'dt', 'col_lag'])
```

Script:

```py
df = df.groupBy("id").agg(
    F.aggregate(
        F.array_sort(F.collect_list(F.struct("dt", "col_lag"))),
        F.expr("array(struct(string(null) dt, 0L col_lag, 0D adstock))"),
        lambda acc, x: F.array_union(
            acc,
            F.array(x.withField(
                'adstock',
                x["col_lag"] + F.lit(0.9) * F.element_at(acc, -1)['adstock']
            ))
        )
    ).alias("a")
)
df = df.selectExpr("id", "inline(slice(a, 2, size(a)))")

df.show()
# +---+----------+-------+------------------+
# | id|        dt|col_lag|           adstock|
# +---+----------+-------+------------------+
# |  1|2020-10-07|      1|               1.0|
# |  1|2020-10-14|      2|               2.9|
# |  1|2020-10-21|      4| 6.609999999999999|
# |  1|2020-10-28|      0|             5.949|
# |  2|2021-09-08|      1|               1.0|
# |  2|2021-09-15|      2|               2.9|
# |  2|2021-09-22|      0|              2.61|
# |  2|2021-09-29|      0|2.3489999999999998|
# +---+----------+-------+------------------+
```

Thorough explanation of the script is provided in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72980095/pyspark-cumulative-sum-with-limits/72982660#72982660).

Comment: This is very helpful. I shall go through the explanation of the script to cement my understanding. Thanks a lot