# How to populate rows of Spark dataframe column based with previous row based on a multiple conditions?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyspark, data-wrangling

Disclaimer: This might be possible duplicate but I cannot find the exact solution. Please feel free to mark this question as duplicate and provide link to duplicate question in comments.

I am still learning python dataframe operations and this possibly has a very simple solution which I am not able to figure out.

I have a spark dataframe around 12 million rows with few columns. Now I want to derive a column from based on the greatest value from two other columns and the derived value of previous row.

Input-

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D | Column E | Column F | Column G |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Apr | 2022 | 3 | 2 | 3 | 0 |
| 1 | May | 2022 | 3 | 2 | 3 | 0 |
| 1 | Jun | 2022 | 3 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | Jul | 2022 | 3 | 2 | 4 | 0 |
| 1 | Aug | 2022 | 3 | 2 | -1 | 0 |
| 1 | Sep | 2022 | 3 | 8 | 3 | 0 |
| 1 | Oct | 2022 | 3 | 2 | 3 | 0 |
| 1 | Nov | 2022 | 3 | 2 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | Dec | 2022 | 3 | 2 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | Jan | 2023 | 3 | 2 | 6 | 0 |
| 1 | Feb | 2023 | 3 | 2 | 5 | 0 |
| 1 | Mar | 2023 | 3 | 2 | 6 | 0 |
| 1 | Apr | 2023 | 3 | 2 | 7 | 0 |
| 1 | May | 2023 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | Apr | 2017 | 3 | 2 | 3 | 0 |
| 2 | Apr | 2017 | 3 | 2 | 3 | 0 |
| 2 | Apr | 2017 | 3 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | Apr | 2017 | 3 | 2 | 4 | 0 |
| 2 | Apr | 2017 | 3 | 2 | -1 | 0 |
| 2 | Apr | 2017 | 3 | 7 | 3 | 0 |

Output-

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D | Column E | Column F | Column G | Column H | Logic |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Apr | 2022 | 3 | 2 | 3 | 0 | 3 | Max of Column E and F |
| 1 | May | 2022 | 3 | 2 | 3 | 0 | 3 | Max of Column E and F and output of Column H previous row |
| 1 | Jun | 2022 | 3 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 3 | Max of Column E and F and output of Column H previous row |
| 1 | Jul | 2022 | 3 | 2 | 4 | 0 | 4 | Max of Column E and F and output of Column H previous row |
| 1 | Aug | 2022 | 3 | 2 | -1 | 0 | 4 | Max of Column E and F and output of Column H previous row |
| 1 | Sep | 2022 | 3 | 8 | 3 | 0 | 8 | Max of Column E and F and output of Column H previous row |
| 1 | Oct | 2022 | 0 | 2 | 3 | 0 | 8 | Max of Column E and F and output of Column H previous row |
| 1 | Nov | 2022 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 8 | Max of Column E and F and output of Column H previous row |
| 1 | Dec | 2022 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 8 | Max of Column E and F and output of Column H previous row |
| 1 | Jan | 2023 | 0 | 0 | 6 | -3 | 6 | If Column G < 0 Max of Column E and F and (output of Column H previous row + Column G) |
| 1 | Feb | 2023 | 0 | 2 | 5 | 0 | 6 | Max of Column E and F and output of Column H previous row |
| 1 | Mar | 2023 | 0 | 2 | 6 | 0 | 6 | Max of Column E and F and output of Column H previous row |
| 1 | Apr | 2023 | 0 | 0 | 7 | 0 | 7 | Max of Column E and F and output of Column H previous row |
| 1 | May | 2023 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 7 | Max of Column E and F and output of Column H previous row |
| 2 | Apr | 2017 | 3 | 2 | 3 | 0 | 3 | Max of Column E and F |
| 2 | Apr | 2017 | 3 | 2 | 3 | 0 | 3 | Max of Column E and F and output of Column H previous row |
| 2 | Apr | 2017 | 3 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 3 | Max of Column E and F and output of Column H previous row |
| 2 | Apr | 2017 | 3 | 2 | 4 | 0 | 4 | Max of Column E and F and output of Column H previous row |
| 2 | Apr | 2017 | 3 | 2 | -1 | 0 | 4 | Max of Column E and F and output of Column H previous row |
| 2 | Apr | 2017 | 3 | 7 | 3 | 0 | 7 | Max of Column E and F and output of Column H previous row |

New Column H needs to be created with following logic

1. Dataframe is populated with distinct values in column A spread across diff month and year and aligned in ascending order.
2. First row of each distinct value in Column A must be maximum of Column E and F
3. Subsequent row value for Column H is maximum of Column E and F and value derived on previous row for column H.(when Column G >=0)
4. If Column G < 0, Column H is maximum of (Column E and F and (column G + previous row value for column H))

Comment: In PySpark, this task is difficult. This is a close example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74146685/sum-two-values-on-the-previous-row?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Also, your input data does not match your output. Please be more careful, as it causes a lot of confusion! Use [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74285763/edit) button to fix mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

understand, there are may tons of similar question but not exakt what your looking for. I hope this helps:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO('''
Column A    Column B    Column C    Column D    Column E    Column F    Column G
1   Apr 2022    3   2   3   0
1   May 2022    3   2   3   0
1   Jun 2022    3   1   1   0
1   Jul 2022    3   2   4   0
1   Aug 2022    3   2   -1  0
1   Sep 2022    3   8   3   0
'''), sep="\t")

# Max of Column E and F
df['Column H'] = df.apply(lambda row: max(row.loc['Column E'], row.loc['Column F']), axis=1)

# Helper column (Column H previous row)
df['tmp'] = df['Column H'].shift(1)

# Max of Column E and F and output of Column H previous row
df['Logic'] = df.apply(lambda row: max(row.loc['Column E'], row.loc['Column F'], row.loc['tmp']), axis=1)

# Delete helper
df.drop("tmp", axis=1)
```

| index | Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D | Column E | Column F | Column G | Column H | Logic |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | Apr | 2022 | 3 | 2 | 3 | 0 | 3 | 3.0 |
| 1 | 1 | May | 2022 | 3 | 2 | 3 | 0 | 3 | 3.0 |
| 2 | 1 | Jun | 2022 | 3 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 3.0 |
| 3 | 1 | Jul | 2022 | 3 | 2 | 4 | 0 | 4 | 4.0 |
| 4 | 1 | Aug | 2022 | 3 | 2 | -1 | 0 | 2 | 4.0 |
| 5 | 1 | Sep | 2022 | 3 | 8 | 3 | 0 | 8 | 8.0 |

In case it does not exactly what you want, it should give you at least some ideas on how to achieve what you want.

Comment: Disclaimer: Some lines in my solution may have a simpler solution. Feel free to add a comment if so

Comment: I tried this, however works only if this needs to be applied across the dataframe. In my problem, Solution needs to be updated for different values for Column A and is not unique. In that case, how can this be twisted. Column A will have ( value 1 with 10 rows, 
 value 2 with 5 rows). Solution has to be applied for each distinct value of Column A. Any leads.

Comment: Can you please provide a simplified example data (only relevant columns, not to many) and the desired output with values?